# Changing the working directory for all steps in Azure Pipelines YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

It's possible to set the working directory for separate scripts:

```yaml
- script: foo
  workingDirectory: bar
```

However, if all the steps are meant to run in a specific directory, it becomes repetitive to define it for each step.

Using `cd` doesn't affect other steps:

```
- script: cd foo
- script: pwd # returns default working dir instead of foo
```

Two specific examples for when this issue matters are:

- when checking out multiple repos as resources, so the default working directory is one level above the checked out repos
- when running a pipeline for a project that's located in a subdirectory (like in a monorepo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the working directory for the tasks, a workaround is to move the files into the default working directory, and a convenient way to do it is using `git-sparse-checkout` like so:

```
git sparse-checkout set example && mv example/{*,.*} . || true
```

The `{*,.*}` part is for also moving the dotfiles, and `|| true` is needed because that also tries to move `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that would mess things up in relation to [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in ADO which are read-only - so I don't think it's possible.

You would be probably better off by checking sources to or copying things to the default working directory right away at the start of the pipeline.